# pig mapreduce modea and UDF jar

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I created own UDF jar and when I run pig in local mode everything works fine. The UDF jar is stored on my local FS.

When I execute pig script in mapreduce mode (-x mapreduce) and UDF jar is also placed in local FS, I got the error below. Could you please advice what is wrong? Do I have to place the UDF jar into HDFS also?

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias sourceData

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias sourceData
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:935)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:746)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:558)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:927)
        ... 13 more
================================================================================
```

UPDATE:

If i execute the pig script (below) in mapreduce mode all works fine:

sd = load 'hdfs://default:8020/hdfs/customerData.csv' using PigStorage(';') as (name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,Birthdate: chararray,Mileage: int,Fuel_Consumption: double);

dump sd;

but when i include at the beginning my UDF function, even i dont call/use it, when i execute the script i got the Iterator error.

**register /root/MyUDF.jar;**

sd = load 'hdfs://default:8020/hdfs/customerData.csv' using PigStorage(';') as (name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,Birthdate: chararray,Mileage: int,Fuel_Consumption: double);

dump sd;

Should I provide the UDF code?

UPDATE2:
this is what i get from the yarn log

```
2016-03-01 11:31:33,399 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: OutputCommitter set in config null
2016-03-01 11:31:33,443 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:225)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(PigOutputFormat.java:275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1499)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1496)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1429)
2016-03-01 11:31:33,457 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Im still getting error:

```
2016-03-07 14:29:48,625 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:235)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(PigOutputFormat.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1499)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1496)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1429)
2016-03-07 14:29:48,628 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Comment: Can you share the complete pig command you are using?

Comment: When tagging your questions, pay attention to the tag summary tooltip that pops up; one of your tags clearly says in big letters, "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Comment: @Mahendra pls see the update

Comment: Try using `sd = load '/home/hdfs/customerData.csv' using PigStorage(';') ... ` and make sure path `/home/hdfs/customerData.csv` (you can select path as per your convenience) exists on HDFS

Comment: this is not a problem with the path, file is there i double checked with hadoop -fs ... As i wrote the issue occurs when I add at the beginning of the script: register /root/MyUDF.jar;

Comment: Im really confused, it looks like pig uses libs located on the system (i dont know how can i find the pig classpath)  My udf code uses same libs but with different version. How can i force pig to stop to use system libs and use correct libs with proper version that i will provide?

Comment: i compile udf jar agains exactly same version of libs... the pom.xml contains same version of hadoop + pig that is installed in the system where code is executed...